# How do I properly build OpenCV 2.3.1 for Qt 4.7 on windows XP?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake, mingw

http://www.barbato.us/2011/03/18/using-opencv2-within-qtcreator-in-windows-2/

I was following this post above on how to use opencv with Qtcreator.
it is mentioned that i had to add *.lib files to my pro in Qtcreator.

I did just that but out of the box those *.lib files that come with opencv were compiled for Microsoft VS. so I again followed another online post on how to build opencv with minGW for use with Qtcreator, here is the link:
http://knowtheabc.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/windows-opencv-and-qt-creator/

but I am not able to get those *.lib files generated, I get *.dll and *.dll.a

I tried to add them to my Qt project but it does not work!
How do I generate those Lib files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are confused about what version to use. If you want to use QtCreator/MinGW you need to build OpenCV with MinGW **and** use the MinGW version of Qt. [Here](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp) is the MinGW build of Qt. You will need to choose the `MinGW Makefiles` target for the CMake build of OpenCV. [Here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide) is the CMake install guide for OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that dll files are dynamic libraries and lib files are static libraries. dll libraries are ok and should work. You can choose the type of library you want to build in configure.
You don't specify details about why dlls are not working.

Comment: I keep getting undefined reference when trying to build my examples in Qt Creator

e.g I get undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)' although I'm using namespace cv and included opencv.cpp .

could you please tell how to specify the type of library from cMake?

Comment: Check the symbol is actually in the library using the tool for discovering symbols (assuming the library is not stripped). You don't have to include source files (cpp as you said), but header files (h or hpp). Sorry, I don't know how that GUI is designed. Check the manual for that.

Comment: sorry, I meant opencv.hpp and not opencv.cpp